# Does Kubrow Breeding allow for other Kubrow Variants?

Tags: warframe

I had a look on the [wiki](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Kubrow) to see how I might be able to obtain other breeds of Kubrow (or Kavat) but I have not been able to find anything that explains how breeding works.

For example, the breeding section explains:

> The Huras Kubrow, Raksa Kubrow, Sahasa Kubrow, Sunika Kubrow, and Chesa Kubrow are acquired through Incubation. The process to breed a Kubrow is shown during the Howl of the Kubrow quest: the player must have a working Incubator segment, a Kubrow Egg, and an Incubator Power Core.
>
> [...] a Random incubation offers no guarantees on the resulting Kubrow's Variant, height, gender, color, or fur pattern.

This states that certain breeds are obtainable through breeding, but then it also states that there is no guarantee of a "variant", when it also lists these particular breeds, and others under "types".

So, for example, if I wanted to get a [Pharaoh Predasite](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Kubrow#Pharaoh_Predasite) Kubrow, is there a chance I can obtain it through breeding - either through Random or Genetic breeding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Predasites](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Predasite?so=search) can not be randomly bred, but can be created with Genetic Templates.  They are more rescued from the Deimos landscape & revitalized with the assistance of Son.   [Vulpaphyla](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Vulpaphyla) operate in much the same way.

- Random Breeding: This just gives you a random creature of the Kubrow or Kavat Species, providing a companion with random type, fur pattern, colors, size, etc.  I think of this as just accepting the genetics of the Egg or Scans in question.
- [Genetic Code Templates](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Genetic_Code_Template): You need two templates for this.  One from each "Parent".  The resulting Companion's attributes will be a recombination of those in the Templates. As Templates are tradable, you should be able to arrange to get them from other players to guarantee the breed or look of your choice.  FWIW, two Templates from the same parent will just produce a clone.
- Special breeding: For Kubrows, draining of your warframe's Helminth Cyst will produce a [Helminth Charger](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Helminth_Charger?so=search), or for Kavats, use of Genetic Code Templates taken from Vasca infected Kavats can give you the [Vasca Kavat](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Vasca_Kavat?so=search). Other than creating a Template Clone, these are the only times you'll be able to get exactly what you want on the 1st try.

Comment: Predasites (and Vulpaphyla) do have a breeding system (at least genetic breeding). So "not bred at all" is wrong.

Comment: Yes you can. If you cannot then why would someone sell/buys their imprint? [Pharaoh](https://warframe.market/items/pharaoh_predasite_imprint) [Medjay](https://warframe.market/items/medjay_predasite_imprint) [Vizier](https://warframe.market/items/vizier_predasite_imprint) and [Sly](https://warframe.market/items/sly_vulpaphyla_imprint) [Panzer](https://warframe.market/items/panzer_vulpaphyla_imprint) [Cresecent](https://warframe.market/items/crescent_vulpaphyla_imprint)

Comment: @Skye-AT.  Thanks.  I was unaware of the templates.  I'll update.